# $\eta$-completed and $\eta$-inverted $KGL$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $\eta \in \pi_{1, 1}\mathbb{S}$ denote the motivic Hopf map and $KGL$ be the motivic ring spectrum representing algebraic K-theory. I have been trying to show that $KGL_\eta^\wedge = KGL$, which in turn will tell me that $KGL[\eta^{-1}]=0$, but I am getting stuck. I know that $\pi_{1, 1}KGL=0$, thus composing $\eta$ with the unit map of $KGL$ gives me a map $S^{1, 1} \to S^{0, 0} \to KGL$ which must be nullhomotopic. This tells me that the unit map must factor through the cofiber of $\eta$. After here I am stuck; I know that $\eta$-completion is the same as localization at $\eta$ but I don't know much else.

Comment: Is $\eta$-completion Bousfield localization w.r.t to the cofiber of $\eta$?

Comment: @VincentBoelens Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly there is a fiber sequence
$$\mathrm{holim}_n S^{n,n}\otimes X\to X \to X^\wedge_\eta,$$
where the limit is taken over the maps $$S^{n,n}\otimes X \simeq S^{n-1,n-1}\otimes S^{1,1}\otimes X\xrightarrow{ \mathrm{id}\otimes \eta\otimes \mathrm{id}}S^{n-1,n-1}\otimes S^{0,0}\otimes X\simeq S^{n-1,n-1}\otimes X.$$
If $X$ is a ring spectrum the equivalence $S^{0,0}\otimes X\simeq X$ is homotopic to $S^{0,0}\otimes X\to X\otimes X\to X$, the composition of the unit map with the multiplication. In the case $X=KGL$ composing this with $$S^{1,1}\otimes KGL\xrightarrow{\eta\otimes\mathrm{id}} S^{0,0}\otimes KGL$$ yields the zero map as you note, and the sequential homotopy limit over zero maps is the zero object, which shows that $KGL\simeq KGL^\wedge_\eta$.

Comment: This might be entirely wrong, since I don't work in motivic homotopy theory. This is the way it would work in ordinary stable homotopy theory. Some of the indexing might need to be cleaned up.

Comment: Alternatively, you can write the completion $X_\eta^\wedge$ as the homotopy limit of $X / \eta^n$.  If you know that $X \otimes \eta \simeq 0$, then all the maps $X \to X / \eta^n$ are equivalences, and thus so is $X \to X_\eta^\wedge$.

Comment: @VincentBoelens Thanks! This was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @JHF Thanks! Your method is just as useful.